# How to create ROS package for Existing C code

Tags: opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have piece of code in C files, I want to integrate it with ROS. What is the procedure to create ROS package for existing C code. Tell me the procedure and link for this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200197/how-to-create-ros-package-for-existing-c-code/) by [Kd](https://answers.ros.org/users/21257/kd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-03-09**:
Duplicate: http://answers.ros.org/question/200205/how-to-use-c-in-ros-or-create-own-ros-package-for-existing-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

U can use system() in ROS

---

Originally posted by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) with karma: 67 on 2014-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0